# in what stage source port is assigned?

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I opened a socket with

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

then send packet with

```
bzero((char *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
  (char *)&serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
serveraddr.sin_port = htons(portno);

sendto(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0, &serveraddr, serverlen);
```

In what stage the source port of the socket is assigned ? in `socket()` or in `sendto()` ?

Does the source port keep unchanged in all calls of `sendto()` function ?

Comment: the call to `bzero()` set all of `serveraddr` to 0x00.  So the call to `bcopy()` is sourcing a field that is all 0x00.  And where are you getting the value `server->h_length`?  So the posted code is nonsense.  Please post code that includes the data declarations, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sendto() perform an implicit bind if you do not call bind() explicitly.

Comment: any standard prouve that ?

Comment: There's simple logic to prove that: `sendto` is the only and latest place the stack can decide that the socket is not yet bound to anything. An implicit bind in `socket` doesn't make a lot of sense, as there could be an explicit one later in the program, and `socket` has no crystal ball.

Comment: If do not call bind(), it will be bind as INADDR_ANY.